# Multiply single-row query with multi-row query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

---

Hi! i have a query like this:
SELECT (subquery1) * (subquery2); The problem is that subquery1 returns 1 row and subquery2 returns more than one row, and i got error 1242: Subquery returns more than one row.
What i want is:
 say subquery2 returns 15 rows for example, i want the following output:

```
subquery2(1) * subquery1
subquery2(2) * subquery1
subquery2(3) * subquery1
subquery2(4) * subquery1
......
......
subquery2(15) * subquery1
```

How can i achieve this? 
thanks

Comment: Show your query with table definitions and also some sample dataset to test

Answer (score 0):

You need to JOIN between whatever tables are in subquery1 and 2.  This will give you the "for each row" functionality you're looking for.  If you give more information, more help will come.